# How do you monitor small changes to an XHR response?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to be alerted to small changes in the responses of a website, which is not my own..  Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Comment: make a request. Compare response with previous response. "alert" any changes. Rinse and repeat

Comment: Maybe do it by making a hash. Maybe not.

Comment: I am not a programmer and I'm going to request for this on upwork but trying not to get hustled.

Comment: good luck with that